# Android - Material Exposed Dropdown Menu options not populating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, material-components-android

I am trying to create a material exposed dropdown menu that is rebuilt when a fragment is revisited. On initial visit to the fragment, the menu is properly created (it helps create a timer). The exposed dropdown menu has seconds, minutes, hours, and days as the options. When you revisit the fragment and I rebuild the dropdown menu, only the previously selected option is there. For example, if I choose seconds, left the fragment, and came back, only seconds is an option for me to choose. Minutes, hours, and days would not be options. Here is how I am building the exposed dropdown menu when you visit the fragment for the first time (this is again working as intended):

```
            val index = stepNumber - 1
        val ctx = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.timeUnitsMenu)
        val newView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
            .inflate(R.layout.timer, null)
        newView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.delete_timer).setOnClickListener { view -> deleteStep(view) }
        stepsContainer = currentView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_steps_container)
        val timerContainer = newView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.timer_settings_container)
        val timeUnitsMenu = newView.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.time_units_menu)
        val timer : LinearLayout = newView.findViewById(R.id.timer_field_layout)
        val timeUnits = resources.getStringArray(R.array.time_units)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_menu_item, timeUnits)
        timeUnitsMenu.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
        timeUnitsMenu.addTextChangedListener { createTimerFields(timerContainer, timeUnitsMenu.text.toString(), index) }
        timeUnitsMenu.setText(getString(R.string.minutes), false)
        stepsContainer.addView(timer, stepNumber - 1)
        stepNumber++
```

And here is the version that is not working in `onCreateView()`:

```
for (i in 0 until stepsList.size) {
    if (stepsList[i] is MutableList<*>) {
        val list = stepsList[i] as MutableList<*>
        val ctx = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.timeUnitsMenu)
        val timerLayout = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.timer, null)
        timerLayout.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.delete_timer).setOnClickListener { timerView -> deleteStep(timerView) }
        val timerContainer = timerLayout.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.timer_settings_container)
        val timeUnitsMenu = timerLayout.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.time_units_menu)
        val timeUnits = resources.getStringArray(R.array.time_units)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(timerLayout.context, R.layout.dropdown_menu_item, timeUnits)
        println("${arrayAdapter.getItem(0)} ${arrayAdapter.getItem(1)} ${arrayAdapter.getItem(2)} ${arrayAdapter.getItem(3)}")
        timeUnitsMenu.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
        timeUnitsMenu.addTextChangedListener { restoreTimerFields(timerContainer, i) }
        val timeUnitsList = ArrayList(listOf(*resources.getStringArray(R.array.time_units)))
        timeUnitsMenu.setText(timeUnitsList[list.size - 1], false)
        stepsContainer.addView(timerLayout, i)
    }
}
```

Please note I have left out some code from the onCreateView() function because its not relevant. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Move the adapter's fill and assignment method to the onResume method.